# Why my table still inserts duplicate data even If I check if the data exists? PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Problem**: I am inserting data in my table `logs` but the important thing is I need to stop the duplication of the name in my table.

here is my what table looks like

```
table: logs

-------------------
id  | name | amount
-------------------
1   | John |  500
2   | John |  500
-------------------
```

The problem with this table is it duplicates the data and what I need is to stop the duplication of the name

**Solution**: Avoid Data Duplication

Here in my code I call if the name exists then the data will not be insert else it will be delete see my code below

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","servername","");
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname');

      $qrQuery = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE code='$qrid' ";
      $qrQuery_run = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery);


        if (isset($_POST['qrname'])) {

         $txtQrvalue = $qrRow['amount'];

          while($qrRow = mysqli_fetch_array($qrQuery_run)){

           //Check if the data exists
            $exist = $num['firstname'];

            if ($exist == 0) {

            //DELETE THE INSERT QR INFO
            $qrQuery5 = "DELETE FROM qrlogs WHERE id = $id";
            $qrQuery_run5 = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery5);
             echo 'Data already exists';

            }else{

            //INSERT THE INFO WHEN THE NAME IS NOT DUPLICATE
            $qrQuery4 = "INSERT INTO qrlogs (cabin_crew,time_scan,qr_amount) VALUES ('".$num['firstname']."',NOW(),'$txtQrvalue')";
            $qrQuery_run4 = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery4);

            }
     }

}
```

Comment: Why delete an existing datarow - then not add a new one ?

Comment: It's not as you say .... The data is not inserted but also the existing row is deleted

Comment: @KneeColas , I need unique data. so if John is the data then it should not be duplicated to John again when I enter another amount

Comment: Ok, but what are you deleting and why

Comment: @KneeColas is there any solution to my codes then? The logic is when the name exists then it should be remove

Comment: @KneeColas , the  duplicate data  that should be delete I only need to insert **ONE** data per users

Comment: @KneeColas , there should only be ONE `John` in the table. that helps?

Comment: Ok - That seems to be what the code does - but you have no error handling - so if any field name mis-spelt or any other error is reason - you're not catching that

Comment: Sorry, your statements are contradictory. The code does not do what you said in your last statement. You delete John regardless - no test to ensure 1 John remains

Comment: @KneeColas - I am sure that the field name is correct and spelled correctly. yeah but you're right no error handling that is missing on my code

Comment: @KneeColas can you give me the right statement please? thank you very much

Comment: Remove the delete - No reason to delete if you have not inserted a duplicate

Comment: @KneeColas ok ill try, but what should i replace delete when I have `else`?

Answer (score 0):

This deals with a problem in your code - but within your code there is no reason clear reason for duplicates to arise - however - post more code if still a problem

```
if ($exist == 0) {

//DELETE THE INSERT QR INFO
$qrQuery5 = "DELETE FROM qrlogs WHERE id = $id";
// .. TAKE OUT .. $qrQuery_run5 = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery5);
 echo 'Data already exists';

}else{

//INSERT THE INFO WHEN THE NAME IS NOT DUPLICATE
$qrQuery4 = "INSERT INTO qrlogs (cabin_crew,time_scan,qr_amount) VALUES ('".$num['firstname']."',NOW(),'$txtQrvalue')";
$qrQuery_run4 = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery4);

}
```

Your test for uniqueness is the following

```
$exist = $num['firstname'];
```

That doesn't look very solid - but without more of your code impossible to say what is the problem

Comment: I have not mentioned, but already tried that code yesterday, still it does not work. the problem with this code is even there is no duplicate data it does not inserts anything, for example, I have an empty table then if i insert data then it does not inserts anything

Comment: Amended answer for above comment - need more of your code

Comment: but why the `echo 'Data already exists` triggers even the table is empty? need more of you help sir please thank you

Comment: First you say you have duplicates, then you say you cannot insert any - now you focus on something else. No, post more code - Cannot answer random varying questions and problems. You need to be precise and concise and show what work you have done

Comment: I updated my code above sir please see. I hope that clears it out as that is just my code.

Comment: Ok.  Where is the $num array coming from ? - You seem to be deciding pre-existence based on that not on what you selected from scratch cards table.

Comment: Also you are checking in scratch cards table not qrlogs so you're not going to find a match anyway - so it will create duplicates. Your first select * from should be on qrlogs surely ?